# com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog

Tags: java, jax-ws

I generated a jax-ws web service client using wsimport from a local wsdl file. Whenever i try to invoke the service i get an error : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
Here is the error stack;

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
```

at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://dataimpact.co.ke/SmsNotificationManagerService/services/SmsNotificationManager"]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.wrapException(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:271)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:114)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.hasWSDLDefinitions(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:275)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:111)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Unknown Source)
    at org.csapi.wsdl.parlayx.sms.notification_manager.v2_3.service.SmsNotificationManagerService.(SmsNotificationManagerService.java:42)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:51)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://dataimpact.co.ke/SmsNotificationManagerService/services/SmsNotificationManager"]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:661)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2134)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2040)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:80)
    ... 12 more

There's something i am missing and i cant figure out what it is. Any help will be high appreciated.

Comment: That generally means you're getting an empty response from the server. What happens if you try hitting the same service endpoint using something like soapui?

Comment: @Ian Roberts the server is supposed to return an empty message body ie `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v2_2/local"> <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body> <loc:notifySmsReceptionResponse/> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: Check the URL to the service - i had same thing, it must end with slash